# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' when updating field value

Tags: mysql

The following query gives me the expected result as in a single col of decimals and blanks:

`SELECT IFNULL(CAST((volume/SharesIssued)*100 AS decimal(2,2)) , '') FROM stock_watch.eod`

RESULT

```
0.33
0.03
0.00
0.02
0.55
0.39
0.00
0.05
0.09
0.06
0.08
0.00
0.00
```

however when I try to add it to to a field like this

`UPDATE stock_watch.eod SET VolumePercentage = IFNULL(CAST((volume/SharesIssued)*100 AS decimal(2,2)) , '')`

I get the following error:
`Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''`

All fields are varchar(45)

The table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE eod (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  code varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  date date DEFAULT NULL,
  open varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  high varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  low varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  close varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  volume varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  SharesIssued varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  VolumePercentage varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  checksum varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY fb_groupbyorder_date_INDEX (date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=270331 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SAMPLE DATA: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=99783ff3e554d63a6c9bd83635322dad)

Comment: Please share the table definition? The error seems you are applying numeric operation on string(varchar) type.

Comment: Apologies, I have just added table create statement. Yes all data types here are strings (Varchar). It seems to work during the SELECT but not during the SET in the UPPDATE.

Comment: what do `select version();` and `select @@sql_mode;` show?

Comment: You should not use cast to round, since that will produce errors in strict mode (though not the error you are seeing, if volume and SharesIssued actually have numbers in all rows).  First do one of `round(volume/SharesIssued*100,2)`, `floor(volume/SharesIssued*10000)/100`, or  `ceil(volume/SharesIssued*10000)/100`, then cast.

Comment: `select @@sql_mode;` give `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: My version is 10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

Comment: This returns different error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=de394c45473d7cdfbf568658ddfb903f

Comment: @FanoFN I have updated that site with some data and it now returns the error. Dividing two nulls will not work.

Comment: Pundip, when you update a dbfiddle it produces a new url; please show the url it gave you showing the error

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I changed sql_mode='' in the my.cnf file. Casting was also creating issues by giving wrong results. Issue was resolved by not casting, which works with sql-mode=''. I accept this is not actually a solution to the error message, but rather a way to get the update to happen and reduce error to warning. However, in my experience, strict mode just tends to make mysql unusable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the `SharesIssued` field is empty and your division of `volume/SharesIssued` there become `0/' '`. This is the cause of the error.

If you update the data like so:

```
UPDATE eod SET SharesIssued=0 WHERE SharesIssued='';
```

And run the `UPDATE` query again, you'll receive `Error 1365: Division by 0` instead but that's now caused by the `SharesIssued=''` being updated to `0`. Instead, since your `sql_mode` is on with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` by default, this will happen. One quick solution to this is by turning off `sql_mode` on the session:

```
SET sql_mode = "";

UPDATE eod 
SET VolumePercentage = CAST(IFNULL(volume/IFNULL(SharesIssued,0),0)*100 AS DECIMAL(2,2));
```

Depending on what tool you use and whether you set it to show *messages* (error, warning etc.), you'll probably get these warning messages:

> Warning 1292: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''
> Warning 1264: Out of range value for column 'CAST((volume/SharesIssued)*100 AS decimal(2,2))' at row 1

But the column `VolumePercentage` will get updated anyhow. Note that `sql_mode` will return to default setting when the MySQL service is restarted.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=26e77d16148fc23caea7ddc2e9e41024)